# Android Webview Load Local Files in to Online Website

Tags: webview

I have made a Webview app to load a online site in to the view.
now i want to save the css and java script files into the app assets dictionary
to save trafik and speed for the website.
But i cant load the picture from the assets dictionary.
can anyone tell me what i am doihng wrong?

mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.XXX.de/android/index.html");

here the html file on an server:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Hallo</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>hans hallo</center>
<center><img src="file:////Android/data/com.news/files/weltuntergang.png" height="200" width="200"></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

> file:///android_asset/

to point to your assets directory

instead of

> file:////Android/data/com.news/files/

probably you will need to use *loadDatawithBaseurl* in your webview for this to work smoothly (in my experience and guidelines recommendation)